# how to use weave to exeute c-code image denoising algorithm?

Tags: c#, python, inline-code, noise-reduction

I have a denoising-algorithm written in C, and I need to use weave.inline to execute the code in order to remove noise from an image. The algorithm doesn't work properly. It says that Weave working on 1D-array, so that's why I have to convert a 2D array to 1D. That's what I have done, but when I send the one 1D array into the C-algorithm, it seems I either get only zeros back, depends on the number of iteration or I get something that seems exactly the same as 1D I sent in. (But when I take the equality test if they are same, it sees that they are not). Can anyone see what's the problem with my algorithm? Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from scipy.weave import inline
from scipy.weave import converters

def weave_iso_difusion_denoising(data0, m, n, kappa, iters):
    """
    Function of removing noise from pictures
   """

    c_code = r"""
     // Fill top and bottom edge
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        data1[m*i*0] = data0[m*i*0];
        data1[i*(n-1)] = data0[i*(n-1)];
    }

    // Fill left and right edges
    for (int i=1; i<n-1; i++) // skip corners
    {
        data1[n*0*i] = data0[n*0*i];
        data1[(n-1)*i] = data0[(n-1)*i];
    }

    for (int iter=0; iter<iters; iter++)
    {
        // Fill interior
        for (int i=1; i<m-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j=1; j<n-1; j++)
            {
                data1[n*i+j] = data0[n*i+j] +kappa*(data0[n*(i-1)+j]
                        +data0[n*i+(j-1)] -4*data0[n*i+j] +
                    data0[n*i+(j+1)] + data0[n*(i+1)+j]);
            }
        }
       tmp = data0;
       data0 = data1;
       data1 = tmp;
    }
    """
    data1 = np.zeros(data0.shape, dtype=data0.dtype)
    data1 = data1.ravel()
    tmp =  np.zeros(data0.shape, dtype=data0.dtype)
    tmp = tmp.ravel()
    var = ['data0', 'm', 'n', 'kappa', 'iters','data1','tmp']
    inline(c_code,var,type_converters=converters.blitz, compiler='gcc')
    return data1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # from image-file to Numpy
    img = Image.open("disaster_before.jpg") # the noisy picture
    data0 = np.array(img.getdata()) # 1D-array
    print 'data0:',data0

    # executing the denoise-program
    kappa = 0.05; iters = 11; n = 375; m = 500
    data2 = weave_iso_difusion_denoising(data0, m, n,kappa, iters)
    print 'data:',data2

    print 'data2 - data0:',np.sum(abs(data2 - data0))

    # from Numpy to image-file
    img1 = Image.new('L', (m,n))
    img1.putdata(data2)
    img1.save("disaster_after_weave_v1.jpg")

output
"""
data0: [156 181 177 ..., 124  35  90]
data: [156 181 177 ..., 124  35  90]
data2 - data0: 18776776 # data0 and data1 is not the same even though they look the same
"""
```

Comment: What does just `data2 - data0` display without the absolute value and sum?

Comment: Also, are you mutating data0 between your print of data0 and the time you print the difference between the two arrays?

Answer (score 0):

With this satement

```
print 'data2 - data0:',np.sum(abs(data2 - data0))
```

you can test if the `data0` and `data1` is the same or they are different. The point is to see if the algorithm does the job.